# How to programmatically set a TextBlock's Grid.Column property

Tags: wpf, f#

So I am following the book [Practical WPF Charts and Graphics](http://www.apress.com/9781430224815). I am at the 3rd code example in Chapter 2. I have been recreating its contents in F# using just code no XAML.

I needed to set a TextBlock's Grid.Column property. Only when I did Autocomplete came up for my TextBlocks there was no grid property, so I researched it and it is called an Attached property.   I looked up [here on the MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011(v=vs.110).aspx).

Unfortunately, despite knowing that and following the MSDN's example I cannot get it to work. I get this error.

```
 1 is not a valid value for property 'Column'
```

I am not really sure what it should be then if 1 is not valid. 
Intellisense in Visual Studio tells me that the second parameter for
[SetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyobject.setvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is an object, which is actually not useful.

Here is my code.

```
type L3Display() as this =
   class
   inherit TextBlock()
   do
   this.Margin <- new Thickness(5.0,10.0,5.0,5.0)
   this.FontSize <- 14.0
   this.HorizontalAlignment <- HorizontalAlignment.Right
   this.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1.0)
   this.TextAlignment <- TextAlignment.Center

   end
```

Here is an example of some of the related XAML in the book

```
   <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2 Margin="5,5,10,5">X2</TextBlock>
```

Comment: If you are going to downvote, that's fine, but at least leave an explanation, considering I did research this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to set ColumnProperty as `integer` not `float`

```
this.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, 1)
```

Comment: I will give that a shot, it doesn't help that so many other things in WPF are floats and the intellisense just tells me the second parameter for SetValue() is an object.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to set the textblock in to the grid? The below code is in vb but this is how I've done it.

```
Dim txt1 As New TextBlock()
txt1.HorizontalAlignment = Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center
txt1.VerticalAlignment = Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center
txt1.Text = ""
contentGrid.Children.Add(txt1)
Grid.SetColumn(txt1, 0)
Grid.SetRow(txt1, 0)
```

The contentGrid is a dynamically created grid in code behind and this is a part of my larger code where I add controls to the grid. Hope it helps.